# Concurency : sharing same memory space

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, shared-memory, directx-11

Is there a way in C++11&|14 to have concurrency with each task sharing the same "memory space", or whatever it is called ?

My problem : I have a bunch of 3D meshes that are "preparing themselves" by (among other things) creating their own buffers (i.e. vertices buffers) using DX11 functions.

What I tried is creating a thread for each object so they can "prepare themselves" in their own thread. Trying to read thread's buffer memory from the main thread after I joined them gives me an read access violation.

I have the feeling (I am no expert) said buffers are local to their thread thus I can't read them anymore - or even they are destroyed @ thread joining.

Is my view correct & Is there a workaround to this issue ?

I'm posting an image rather than code.

[image: schema]

Breaking on :

```
// Update shader interface
pDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(this->meshShaderInterfaceBuffer, 0, nullptr, &(this->meshShaderInterface), 0, 0);
```

[image]

Error code : `Exception thrown at 0x759FD09C (kernel32.dll) in dxmed.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.`

**EDIT** As requested, some code excerpts.

```
// I create an ObjModel on the heap
// At this point, ObjModel populates itself with ObjMesh's (model parts)
ObjModel test = new ObjModel("media/models/some_model.obj");

// I call the prepare for rendering method on parent ObjModel
// To make my model drawable. g_d3dDevice is part of the DX11
// context variables. prepareForRendering() definition being:
//    bool prepareForRendering(
//        ID3D11Device* pDevice,
//        bool prepareTextures = true,
//        bool prepareVertices = true,
//        bool prepareBuffers = true,
//        D3D11_FILTER filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR,
//        D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE addressMode = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP);
if (!test->prepareForRendering(g_d3dDevice)) return false;

// The prepare for rendering func calls an evenly named func
// on all it's ObjMesh's. This part is causing problems
// apparently when trying to thread it. Code below attempting
// to thread it - inside ObjModel::prepareForRendering(...)
std::vector<std::thread*> pthreads;
for (ObjMesh& mesh : this->meshes) {
    std::thread* t = new std::thread(&ObjMesh::prepareForRendering, &mesh, pDevice, prepareTextures, prepareVertices, prepareBuffers, filter, addressMode);
    pthreads.push_back(t);
}

for (std::thread* t : pthreads) {
    if (t->joinable()) t->join();
}

// After that, I am good to draw() my model. Inside a Render() func.
// Which calls again the draw() func of all it's ObjMesh's
//    void ObjModel::draw(ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext, D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY topology) const {
//      if (this->meshes.size() == 0) {
//    #ifdef _DEBUG
//          std::cerr << "Model hasn't any meshes to draw!" << std::endl;
//          MessageBox(nullptr, std::to_string(this->meshes.size()).c_str(), "wtf?", MB_OK);
//    #endif
//      }
//      else {
//          for (const ObjMesh& mesh : this->meshes) {
//              mesh.draw(pDeviceContext, topology);
//          }
//      }
//    }
test->draw(g_d3dDeviceContext);

// Finally, mesh draws itself. Code breaks at ObjMesh trying
// to access it's own buffers (created in the threaded prepareForRendering())

void ObjMesh::draw(ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext, D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY topology) const {

    // Whole bunch of stuff...
    // when suddenly...

    // Update shader interface
    pDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(this->meshShaderInterfaceBuffer, 0, nullptr, &(this->meshShaderInterface), 0, 0);

    // (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ a wild Access violation reading location 0x12345678 appears ;(

    // Draw
    pDeviceContext->Draw(vertex_data.size(), 0);

    return;
}
```

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: If they are threads inside the same process then you should be able to see data from one thread in another - although you should be aware of thread safety issues.

Comment: Where does my read access violation possibly come from then ? I am only attempting reading after all threads are joined, and no thread tries to read another thread.

Comment: You are asking us to debug code we cannot see. Can you create minimal, self-contained code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: And make sure you put full descriptions of the errors etc and how the lines in any stack traces line up to the code, etc

Comment: You can use OpenMP [openmp](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/)

Comment: Please use words rather than obscure punctuators.

Comment: Are you creating the DX11 buffers on different threads?

Comment: You want to distinguish between kernel-scheduled threads (which may share some resources) and user-scheduled threads (which share most resources). Unfortunately there is no common nomenclature distinguishing them, nor common OS/library support. Look up light-weight processes, clone(2), fibers, etc.

Comment: In C++11, you have [atomic shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) made to share memory between threads. **EDIT : apparently, it's broken and should no be used**

Comment: @DragonRock: That's completely broken. You have to wait for `atomic_shared_ptr` in C++17...

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't know that, thanks for the precision

Comment: If you suppose them to be thread-local, try copying those buffers to the general memory before exiting the thread and see what happens.

Comment: Matter of fact : I don't know how DX11 allocates buffer memory. All I know is reading them from thread 'main' gives me an Memory Acces Violation error. Would it make any difference to use `asyinc` rather than `thread` ? @Robinson yes precisely.

Comment: Honestly, we can't tell without seeing the code. Really. There is probably some simple bug in your code, such as a missing lock or use of a resource in one thread before it's initialized in another. But we need to see the code to find it. Can you reproduce this problem in a minimal, compilable example?

Comment: I updated my answer - please see my code excerpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : some of my buffers didn't even get the chance to get created because I was aborting the `prepareForRendering` function in some cases before the buffer creation part. Cases being : attempting to create texture ressources from file (`CreateWICTextureFromFileEx` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My texture creation (all) failed unexpectedly because of the COM interface they require wasn't setup to work in multi-threaded mode (see - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `CoinitializeEx`).

Which brings me back to start because I can't initialize my Ribbon Framework with a multi-threaded COM interface... :(

Anyone expert on this ?

**EDIT** Solved : `CoInitialize` can be called several times (using `CoUninitialize`).